# How to determine a webpage is compressed with Live HTTP Headers?

Tags: header, gzip

When I look at every page in live http headers, the page contains the below parts in header:

```
Accept Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content Encoding: Gzip
```

When I use websites to check whether it is compressed or not, it says it's not compressed. How can we be sure that a page is compressed?
For example I tested [this site](http://www.itsanat.com) in [Gzip tester](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) and it says it's not compressed, but I see Content Encoding in live http headers.

Answer (score 0):

Your headers are wrong, it should be:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

so basically: dashes not spaces between words in the headername

It's your webserver that needs to add those and do the compression, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html